# Would like to change the cursor to an on-the-fly generated cursor image

Tags: javascript, dom, cursor

My web app receives events from the server to change the cursor to a specified .cur file, and this .cur file is sent as a PNG to the browser (over WebRTC data channel). Is it possible to set the cursor to this in-memory .cur image ?

The line below will change the cursor to a .cur image stored at a URL.
But, I would like to generate the cursor on the fly.

```
document.getElementById("video-container").style.cursor = "url('http://wiki-devel.sugarlabs.org/images/e/e2/Arrow.cur'), auto";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply add the url to your image as cursor.

Something like this:

```
channel.onmessage = (event) => {
  const blob = new Blob([event.data], { type: "image/png" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var elm = document.getElementById("video-container");
  elm.style.cursor = "url('" + url + "'), auto";
};
```

Make sure to release the used memory with [URL.revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) after you've set the cursor.

Comment: Thanks, @kirschkern. Can I not simply call `revokeObjectURL` right after setting the cursor style ?

Comment: @Jacko You may test if this works. IMHO you need to wait for the URL to be loaded. If you call revokeObjectURL right after setting the cursor it might not be fully loaded yet. You could either call it for a previous cursor every time a new one will be set, or you may try, if it works when you create a new image and wait for the image's "load" event.

Comment: thank you. One last question: if I send a .cur file as my event.data, what MIME type would that be to load into a blob ?

Comment: You may try "image/x-icon" or "image/vnd.microsoft.icon".